# Display vertical lines (Indent Guides) in ASP.NET web forms to line up elements

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have searched the Tools > Options menu and I can not find how to display the vertical lines that line up elements in ASP.Net Web Forms for Visual Studio 2015.
I know this will be simple but does anyone know how to do this or if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was after was actually this plugin.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides

It adds indent guides.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `Ruler and Grid`, found under `View`.
You can configure the Grid under `Tools > Options > Web Forms Designer > Ruler and Grid` or by clicking the `Configure` option in the Rules and Grid menu.
I found it useful to enlarge the `Spacing` in the options to enlarge the grid.

(This is for Visual Studio 2017)